# .xprofile and startup applications' scripts stop working after a few minutes in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: unity, gnome, startup-applications, touchegg

I am running Ubuntu with a few scripts on .xprofile and some on startup applications, and I noticed that either today or a few days ago those scripts stopped working.

Well they didn't. They actually do run for about 5 to 10 minutes and they they get reversed.
My scripts in .xprofile are to allow touchegg to run:

```
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient ClickFinger2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
touchegg &
```

And in startup applications I have things like:

```
sleep 20 && setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:swapcaps
```

Then, when I turn on the computer, touchegg is working, the caps and control keys are swapped. But only for a few minutes. Then suddenly everything gets reverted. The caps is back in its place, and touchegg is not working anymore. Usually happens a within 5 to 10 minutes after the computer is on. Any ideas??

Thank you!

ps: I had installed gnome-pomodoro app which I think downloaded a bunch of gnome stuff and I read online that gnome-session could be overwriting my scripts. So I uninstalled most of the gnome-session packages (I accidentally also deleted unity 7, so i had to reinstall it). But my problem remained the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't found a reason for why the scripts that used to work suddenly stopped working, other than I performed updates on Ubuntu and switched to Kernel 4.10.

However, I got a way around that by putting all of my scripts into a .sh file. I made it executable by running

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

And I call that from startup applications.
I also modified that startup application file (in my case it's called start_script.desktop and it is located in .config/autostart/), and added the line:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=3
```

Finally, another thing that I noticed is that my commands used to be something like:

```
sleep 20; setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:swapcaps
```

So maybe now it is not allowed to have multiple commands in one line?